# Service Bus Support

Tags: nservicebus, operation

I’m new here, sorry if this is somehow a dumb question or if it’s been covered, but I can’t find an answer anywhere!!

I am trying to figure out how other companies provide support for alerts generated from activity on their service busses? I can find basically no information through google searching though. What am I missing?? I am not a developer, but I am in IT. (Just for illustration purposes, our alerts go to Slack at the moment. But support is a mess after that.)

I'm interested in who receives the messages, the support structure and what are the positions/titles of the people doing the support, and to what extent they do work and then who do they escalate to?

Basically... what happens after an alert is produced? We display them to Slack. What do others use to display the alerts?

What is a good online resource for these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 1):

> alerts generated from activity on their service busses

Disclaimer: I work at [Particular Software](https://particular.net/), makers of [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/)

This is a very generic question and hard to answer. There are many different opinions on what a [servicebus actually is](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/architecture/). If you're asking me, activity on the bus could be messages being sent or published. If you're interested in that, you should collect metrics. NServiceBus has a [plugin for that](https://docs.particular.net/monitoring/metrics/install-plugin) and a [tool to show](https://docs.particular.net/monitoring/metrics/in-servicepulse) those metrics. We have a [video showing this](https://particular.net/real-time-monitoring).

Another possibility is when something goes wrong. You want to monitor the [endpoint](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/concept-overview#endpoint), possibly poison queues (dlq), etc. Or be notified when an [error message arrives](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/contracts) or when an endpoint stops sending heartbeats.

And maybe I didn't even cover your question. But I think I got most topics.

Comment: Hey Dennis!  Thanks for the links, I’ll definitely review them. 

The monitoring of the alerts from events the endpoints is already happening through slack. My question is about the people / org structure, rather than the technology. So, I’m more wondering about what does the support team look like at other companies?  Like, titles and tiers of support and the skill sets of those people. 

Thanks!!!